# Suppose the cofficients of a quadratic are rational. How can we use the discriminant to determine if the roots are also rational?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Suppose the cofficients of a quadratic are rational. How can we use the discriminant to determine if the roots are also rational?

Firstly the discriminant has to be nonnegative.

I've had a read of [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). I kinda get it but i'm not quite sure how to apply it to find a solution for the problem.

$$\sqrt{b^2-4ac} = \frac{p}{q}$$, where $p, q \in \mathbb{Z} $ and are coprime.
$$b^2-4ac =  \frac{p^2}{q^2}$$
$$ q^2(b^2-4ac) = p^2$$
Am I going in the right direction ? I want reason that some $p/q$ does exist. Please guide me.

Comment: I think you have this turned around.  It is *pre*sumed that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are given.  One then computes the single number $d = b^2 - 4ac$.  Either this $d$ is or it is not a square rational number -- there is no solving to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if the roots are rational, you need to check if the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ (which is a rational number $s/t$) is a square of a rational number. We can assume that the fraction $s/t$ is in the lowest terms, i.e., $s$, $t$ are coprime integers. Then you just need to find out if $s$ and $t$ are perfect squares (of integers).

For example $1/2x^2-x+1/4$ has discriminant $1/2$ but $2$ is not a perfect square, so the roots are not rational. On the other hand, $1/2x^2-3/2x+1$ has discriminant $9/4-2=1/4$, where both $1$ and $4$ are perfect squares, so roots are rational.

Comment: So we really answer this probelm  rhetorically? And end by saying either $s$ and $t$ are perfect squares or not. There is no solving to be done?

Comment: I don't quite understand the first sentence of your comment. Note that $s$ and $t$ are integers, not arbitrary rational numbers. To check that, say, $s$ is a perfect square, one needs, for example, to find its prime decomposition. Does this qualify for "solving"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the answer you gave is mainly words. Not a long drawn out algebra equations. I assume this is because for example it isn't possible to do a prime decomposition on variable.

Comment: We don't have say much/do much to conclude this solution.

Comment: To check if $s$ or $t$ is a square, you may need to say a lot. It is quite difficult in general. There are other methods to find rational solutions, and it is not clear which method is faster.